# JS Firebase Database Error db.ref is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to implement firebase realtime database API in my website, I am following this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#node.js but I get this error:

[image]

this is my code:

```
 <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getDatabase } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-database.js";;

    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xx.x.xxx",
      databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      projectId: "xxxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
      appId: "xxxxx",
      measurementId: "xxxxxxx"
    };

    const fireapp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getDatabase(fireapp);
    const ref = db.ref('server/saving-data/fireblog');
  </script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Could the version I am using be incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing the new modular/v9 syntax of the API with the older namespaced syntax, and that won't work.

In v9 the equivalent of that last line is:

Add "`ref`" to the `import`s from `firebase/database`:

```
import { getDatabase, ref } 
  from "<wherever you are getting firebase/database from>";
```

And replacing your last line:

```
const dbref = ref(db, 'server/saving-data/fireblog');
```

Since you seem to be taking outdated code, I recommend keeping the documentation handy (for example, this section on [getting a reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#get_a_database_reference)) to compare the v8 and v9 code samples, as well as reading the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Comment: Your code give me this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ref' before initialization

Comment: I had already thought about doing this but got that res () was not defined

Comment: `ref` you mean? Did you add it to the `import`? `import { getDatabase, ref } from ...`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [Firebase Client SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) but referring to the documentation of [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) that is not totally modular yet. Try refactoring the code using `ref()` function:

```
import { ref } from "firebase/database"

const dbRef = ref(db, 'server/saving-data/fireblog');
```

Checkout the documentation of [Firebase JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) (the <kbd>Modular</kbd> tab) for correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're using the documentation for the NodeJS backend SDK. Your starting point for frontend developing should be [firebase docs – web start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

For v9 of the Web-SDK, that you included into your website, there different functions to use. Check out [firebase docs – web read/write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) for using them.

I was confused as well when I first used firebase for web developing some weeks ago. I hope it helps.